# Getting system.object instead of a value in csv file exported from powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, inventory

I have this script to export VM Tags from azure but when i export the csv file the tags values coulmn has System.Object instead of the tag key and its value. Your kind help would be great

```
# Sign into Azure Portal
connect-azaccount

# Fetch the Virtual Machines from the subscription
$azureVMDetails = get-azvm

# Fetch the NIC details from the subscription
$azureNICDetails = Get-AzNetworkInterface | ?{ $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null}

#Fetching Virtual Machine Details
$virtual_machine_object = $null
$virtual_machine_object = @()

#Iterating over the NIC Interfaces under the subscription
foreach($azureNICDetail in $azureNICDetails){ 

    #Fetching the VM Name
    $azureVMDetail = $azureVMDetails | ? -Property Id -eq $azureNICDetail.VirtualMachine.id 
    #Fetching the VM Tags   
    $vm_tags = Get-AzVM | Select-Object -Property (
    @{name='Tags'; expression = {($_.tags.GetEnumerator().ForEach({ '{0} = {1}' -f $_.key, $_.value }) -join ',')}}
    )
    #VM Details export
    $virtual_machine_object_temp = new-object PSObject 
    $virtual_machine_object_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "name" -Value $azureVMDetail.Name
    $virtual_machine_object_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "comments" -Value $vm_tags
    $virtual_machine_object += $virtual_machine_object_temp
}  

#Report format and path  
$virtual_machine_object | Export-Csv "C:\Users\JOHN\Desktop\Inventory_$(get-date -f dd.MM.yyyy).csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Comment: Change `-Value $vm_tags` to `-Value $vm_tags.Tags`

Comment: Thank you for your answer and i have changed it to $vm_tags.Tags but still same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the property value you're adding is the actual `Tags` strings you generated in the previous step by passing `$vm_tags.Tags` rather than just `$vm_tags`.

Additionally, as there might be more than one VM returned by `Get-AzVM`, you'll want to `-join` all the resulting values together at the end:

```
$virtual_machine_object_temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "comments" -Value ($vm_tags.Tags -join ';')
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and sorry im really new to Powershell. 
But somehow there is something wong with my script because now i am getting only one tag value applied to all the VMs. Could you help to change this plus each VM has more that one tags and i wanted to have one per line.

Comment: @John of course it does - you asked it to! :) If you want only the tags from the VM that owns the NIC, use a nested loop so you have a variable that references the current VM inside the loop over the NICs, or replace `Get-AzVM | Select ...` with `$azureNICDetail.VirtualMachine |Select ...`

Comment: Now its returning me a blanc coulmn of comments

Comment: nevermind. i have got another soultion but thanks for your kind help :)